# SQL: Can I display comment next to a table row depending on the value?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table `Employees` with 
`empl_nr, start_date, empl_name, sex, empl_unit`
where `unit` is in `1,2,3`

I want to display one additional column which is not in the table with comments depending on values in the table.

I.E if `unit='1'` that means they work for Paris and I'd like to display that; if employee started work in 2016 then he is a new comer and I would like to display that info example below

Answer (score 2):

You need `CASE`. For example:

```
/* build a test case */
with test(n, y) as (
    select 1, 2016 from dual union all
    select 2, 2000 from dual
)
/* the query */
select n,
       case
        when n = 1 then 'comment when n=1'
        when n = 2 then 'comment when n=2'
       end
       || ' and ' ||
       case
        when y > 2010 then 'year greater than 2010'
        else 'year <= 2010'
       end as comm
from test;
```

gives:

```
         N COMM
---------- -------------------------------------------
         1 comment when n=1 and year greater than 2010
         2 comment when n=2 and year <= 2010
```